# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.util'

Tags: python, django, pip

I tried to install `importlib.util` using `pip` by running the following command:

```
pip install importlib
```

But cmd throws below error

> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.util'`

Here is the complete error:

[image]

Comment: what  version of python are you using? Seems like 3.6 , try pip3 install importlib

Comment: @Flika205 thank you! easy_install did work for me.

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to install `importlib`, it's already built-in.

From image it looks like you are using Python 3.6 and [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/importlib.html) was imported into python builtins since *Python 3.1*.